How does Jenkins request the backend SSE (server end event) interface and return real-time results to the browser?
I have a backend interface that receives SSE requests and can return real-time execution logs. I want to view the real-time logs in "Console Output" in Jenkins. How should I initiate SSE requests through Jenkins
I have tried using Jenkins' shared libraries. Initiate an SSE request through the okhttp-sse package, but cannot display logs in real-time
